# Reading custom user dictionary

Tags: javascript

Every OS keeps a custom dictionary of user-learned words. Some browsers also keep an additional extra custom dictionary too (Chrome for example).

Is it possible to read all/any of these custom dictionaries in JavaScript?
Since "dictionaries" are a data construct, Googling anything to do with dictionaries and JavaScript leads me to irrelevant things.

EDIT: Dictionaries for words spellings - this one is mine:

[image]

Comment: If you could access the dictionary from the website, that would be a security/privacy leak. You can access it from a browser extension, though.

Comment: Of course, but i'm hoping if it's as simple as "Allow 'mysite.com' to access '/Users/Bergi/Spellings/Custom'?" people will be inclined to hit yup.

Comment: No, I don't think there is such an API. Get in contact with the W3 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like for Google Chrome the custom dictionary is [kept in a local file](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/it8EDksvHdc).

[Firefox](http://perishablepress.com/how-to-edit-the-firefox-custom-dictionary/) keeps a similar local file, but it would be harder to determine exactly which directory to pull from without searching the file system.

And, unsurprisingly, same idea for [Internet Explorer](http://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/custom-dictionary-in-ie-10/1766) (at least 10 and up)

Comment: I can't vote you because I don't have enough rep - but thank you StephenH that's perfect :)

Comment: Glad to help. I'm sure some friendly StackOverflow veteran will vote me up for you ;-) Just remember that granting access permissions to read the file system via the browser might be tricky from Javascript.

Comment: I think to find the dictionary for Firefox isn't that *hard* any more: type-in the address `about:profiles` and open the root folder. Found at: [Profiles - Where Firefox stores your bookmarks, passwords and other user data (section How do I find my profile?)](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Install-and-Update/Profiles-Where-Firefox-stores-your-bookmarks-passwords-and-other/ta-p/4608#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile) Thanks for initiating this research.